# Can I approximate stock using gelatin, MSG and water?

Tags: soup, stock, broth, stews, chicken-stock

From looking at different sources about stocks and broths, I understood that the main goal of simmering the bones for a long time is to extract as much gelatin and glutamate as we can from them. So I was wondering if it would be possible to approximate stock by just boiling water with appropriate amounts of gelatin and MSG. Would this work? Maybe I could boil the aromatics like mirepoix in the water along with the aforementioned ingredients. If there is any research into this subject I'd be glad if anyone could share it with me.

Comment: What is the purpose of this experiment? What do you want to use your artificial stock for?

Comment: Simmering stock is to concentrate the flavors, having gelatin is a by-product.

Comment: @Max - gelatin is not entirely a by-product; it does contribute to the taste of what you end up cooking the stock with. Just in its role as a thickener, it changes the mouthfeel and also slows down the movement of the food through your mouth to allow you to more thoroughly taste the other flavours.

Comment: This is purely for convenience sake. I'm from a small town in India, carton stock is not available at all. And I do make my own stock from bones, but it's somewhat inconvenient.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it and it will work.

In fact, there is a huge market for products doing exactly that. You may know them as "bouillon cubes" but they exist in versions other than cubes, such as powder or liquid. They are a combination of MSG and aromatics, usually also salt. They rarely use gelatin, since the gelatin is actually a side effect of making stock and not necessary for the taste, but there are a few products which include thickeners, if you prefer those.

So, if you want to experiment, go ahead, if not, you might find it more convenient to use an existing product that has been formulated so it "just works".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would use store bought carton stock or bouillon cubes if they were available in my town or available cheaply online. Not the case unfortunately. I'll look for homemade bouillon without making stock first. Thanks again.